# Which folder on AWS EC2 for my private Python scripts?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux) instance configured with a LAMP web server on it as well. On top of having a small website hosted there I'd like it to run in the background a few Python scripts with cron.

Those scripts are private and separate from the website, so I don't want them in the `/var/www/html` folder.

On my personal computer those would stay in my User's Documents folder, but being new at having a server (and linux) I don't know where to put them.

By common practice, is there a specific folder I should use ?

Comment: `/opt` is enough . https://askubuntu.com/a/195658/159179

Comment: Without `/var/www/html` directory, how to edit/update file without any additional application ? Use `mongodb` create a `root_login_web_page` save scripts as  `db` entry and/or `encrypt` `db` entry dynamically(so secure ? Yes !). **Linux run on `db` system, why your scripts not !**

Comment: Thanks, I will use both recommendations. `/opt` initially for immediate usage. And I will look at `mongodb` at a later stage as it seems still a bit advanced to me now.